# Upsert to CosmosDB from Spark error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-cosmosdb

I am really new to Spark/CosmosDB/Python, so I am going through code samples from MS site and GitHub while trying to create something on my own. After long fight with Spark-CosmosDB connector, I am able to read the data from CosmosDB collection. Right now I would like to do the opposite (upsert), but found another obstacle. Here is the example, which I am reffering to:
[Writing to Cosmos DB section](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark).

I am able to read from Cosmos, and do stuff with the data, but I am not able to insert back to Cosmos. Below is my slightly modified code:

```
%%configure
{ "name":"Spark-to-Cosmos_DB_Connector", 
  "jars": ["wasb:///example/jars/1.0.0/azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.2.0_2.11-1.1.0.jar", "wasb:///example/jars/1.0.0/azure-documentdb-1.14.0.jar", "wasb:///example/jars/1.0.0/azure-documentdb-rx-0.9.0-rc2.jar", "wasb:///example/jars/1.0.0/json-20140107.jar", "wasb:///example/jars/1.0.0/rxjava-1.3.0.jar", "wasb:///example/jars/1.0.0/rxnetty-0.4.20.jar"],
  "conf": {
    "spark.jars.excludes": "org.scala-lang:scala-reflect"
   }
}

# Read Configuration
readConfig = {
  "Endpoint" : "https://doctorwho.documents.azure.com:443/",
  "Masterkey" : "SPSVkSfA7f6vMgMvnYdzc1MaWb65v4VQNcI2Tp1WfSP2vtgmAwGXEPcxoYra5QBHHyjDGYuHKSkguHIz1vvmWQ==",
  "Database" : "DepartureDelays",
  "preferredRegions" : "Central US;East US2",
  "Collection" : "flights_pcoll", 
  "SamplingRatio" : "1.0",
  "schema_samplesize" : "1000",
  "query_pagesize" : "2147483647",
  "query_custom" : "SELECT c.date, c.delay, c.distance, c.origin, c.destination FROM c WHERE c.origin = 'SEA'"
}

# Connect via azure-cosmosdb-spark to create Spark DataFrame
flights = spark.read.format("com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark").options(**readConfig).load()
flights.count()

# Write configuration
writeConfig = {
 "Endpoint" : "https://doctorwho.documents.azure.com:443/",
 "Masterkey" : "SPSVkSfA7f6vMgMvnYdzc1MaWb65v4VQNcI2Tp1WfSP2vtgmAwGXEPcxoYra5QBHHyjDGYuHKSkguHIz1vvmWQ==",
 "Database" : "DepartureDelays",
 "Collection" : "flights_pcoll",
 "Upsert" : "true"
}

# Write to Cosmos DB from the flights DataFrame
flights.write.format("com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark").options(**writeConfig).save()
```

So, when I try to run this, I get:

```
An error occurred while calling o90.save.
: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Writing in a non-empty collection.
```

After quick googling, I tried to add mode("append"), to my last line:

```
flights.write.format("com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark").mode("append").options(**writeConfig).save()
```

Unfortunately, this leaves me with an error that I am not able to understand:

```
An error occurred while calling o127.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 4.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 4.0 (TID 90, wn2-MDMstr.zxmmgisclg5udfemnv0v3qva3e.ax.internal.cloudapp.net, executor 2): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/microsoft/azure/documentdb/bulkexecutor/DocumentBulkExecutor
```

Here is full stacktrace: [error in pastebin](https://pastebin.com/tQKQu6Uf)

Can somebody help me out with this error? I have also receieved exactly same error when working with my own cosmosDB, not the example one from the documentation.

I am using Jupyter notebook with PySpark3 Kernel. Spark version 2.2, HDInsight cluster 3.6.

**EDIT**
I didn't want to just sit waiting for a reply, so I tried the same thing with Scala. Guess what? Same error (or at least very similar): [Scala error](https://pastebin.com/UJdSufLp)

Here is my Scala code for that:

```
%%configure
{ "name":"Spark-to-Cosmos_DB_Connector", 
  "jars": ["wasb:///example/jars/1.0.0/azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.2.0_2.11-1.1.0.jar", "wasb:///example/jars/1.0.0/azure-documentdb-1.14.0.jar", "wasb:///example/jars/1.0.0/azure-documentdb-rx-0.9.0-rc2.jar", "wasb:///example/jars/1.0.0/json-20140107.jar", "wasb:///example/jars/1.0.0/rxjava-1.3.0.jar", "wasb:///example/jars/1.0.0/rxnetty-0.4.20.jar"],
  "conf": {
    "spark.jars.excludes": "org.scala-lang:scala-reflect"
   }
}

import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.schema._
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark._
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.config.Config

val readConfig = Config(Map(
  "Endpoint" -> "https://$my_cosmos_db.documents.azure.com:443/",
  "Masterkey" -> "$my_key",
  "Database" -> "test",
  "PreferredRegions" -> "West Europe",
  "Collection" -> "$my_collection", 
  "SamplingRatio" -> "1.0"
))
val docs = spark.read.cosmosDB(readConfig)

docs.show()

val writeConfig = Config(Map(
  "Endpoint" -> "https://$my_cosmos_db.documents.azure.com:443/",
  "Masterkey" -> "$my_key",
  "Database" -> "test",
  "PreferredRegions" -> "West Europe",
  "Collection" -> "$my_collection", 
  "WritingBatchSize" -> "100"
))




val someData = Seq(
    Row(8, "bat"),
    Row(64, "mouse"),
    Row(-27, "test_name")
)

val someSchema = List(
  StructField("number", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("name", StringType, true)
)

val someDF = spark.createDataFrame(
  spark.sparkContext.parallelize(someData),
  StructType(someSchema)
)

someDF.show()

someDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).cosmosDB(writeConfig)
```

Maybe this would be helpful in troubleshooting.

Thanks!

Comment: did you solve the issue? If yes, could you please post a solution?

Comment: @DavidGreenshtein - Yes and no :) I have added my answer, please check if any of tips will help you.

Comment: thank you @Jangcy for your detailed response, using the uber jar approach with proper HDI and Spark versions made a work for me using Jupyther Notebook. I posted my working configuration in the answer as well

Answer (score 3):

For the first issue when using `python`, please note that you are using the `doctorwho` Azure Cosmos DB collection.  This is a demo collection where we provided the read-only key but not write-key.  Hence the error you are receiving is lack of write access to the collection.

For the second issue, the error from pastebin looks the same. Saying this, some quick observations:

- Are you using HDI 3.6, if you are this is on Spark 2.1 and the JAR being used is for Spark 2.2.  If you're using HDI 3.7, then it's on Spark 2.2 and then you're using the correct jar.
- You may want to use the maven coordinates to get the latest version of the JARs.  Please note `azure-cosmosdb-spark` > [Using Jupyter Notebooks](https://github.com/azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark#using-jupyter-notebooks) for more information.

Comment: Hi Denny.
About first issue (when using `python`), unfortunately I receive the very same error when I try to upsert to my own Cosmos database. I made sure that I am using Read-write primary key to this database.

Regarding second one, my cluster parameters:

`Cluster type, HDI version
Spark 2.2 on Linux (HDI 3.6)`

`Head Nodes, Worker nodes
D3 v2 (x2), D12 v2 (x2)`

Based on this - should I use connector for 2.2, correct?
I will try to check your latest link to see some details. If you came up with something else, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, after whole day of trying, I was not able to upsert the data - I tried with different jars, including uber- ones, and still no luck. I am now thinking of trying to use older cluster (3.5) to check if I will succeed in upserting - maybe there is something bad with connector itself?

Comment: Sorry that you're running issues - could you ping me directly at denny [dot] lee [at] microsoft.com and perhaps I can help?

Comment: Denny, thanks a lot for your help and time spent on this problem. I know that we have figured out some workarounds for this. Please check my answer and correct me if I was wrong at some point. I keep my fingers crossed for MS team for the new version of connector and I hope it will work fine in Zeppelin, Jupyter and via SSH :)

Answer (score 2):

After a communication with Microsoft engineers and few tests conducted by myself, I found out, that there are some issues about Spark-CosmosDB connector. Basicly, the best version of the connector to be used is **1.0.0**, dated     15-Nov-2017(Both for **Spark 2.1 and 2.2**). [Link to the repository](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.microsoft.azure%22%20AND%20a%3A%22azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.2.0_2.11%22) Below are few solutions/workarounds that worked for me. You may try to experiment with them to find best solution for you.

1) If you work with Spark 2.1 or 2.2, use connector in version 1.0.0 (link above). At the time I am writing this answer (18-May-2018), the latest version of connector is 1.1.1 dated  23-Mar-2018 - it fails when there is a need to write data frame to Cosmos DB or when trying to count over 50k document data frame read from Cosmos (what is 50k docs for no-SQL db?).

2) If you use Spark 2.1 -> Jupter will work with 1.0.0 connector. If you use Spark 2.2 - > Do not use Jupyter notebook - it has some issues with using external packages, especially in Spark 2.2 installation. 
 Please use Zeppelin notebook instead (**with 1.0.0 connector**). Once you opened Zeppelin, in top-right corner click user, then Interpreter. Go to Livy interpreter settings click edit and add package coordinates: `com.microsoft.azure:azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.2.0_2.11:1.0.0`

[image]
[image]

Save and restart interpreter. Then create a new notebook using livy2 interpreter. One note, that in every cell in Zeppelin, you have to add `%pyspark` magic command in first line. Run of first cell would last 1-2 mins because of starting whole app.

3) Instead of using notebooks, you can use your cluster directly. Use putty to SSH into your cluster, using sshuser and password provided when creating the cluster:

[image]

Then start pyspark attaching the uber-jar file (you have to download the uber-jar file from repository then upload it to blob storage connected to your cluster. In my case file is in folder called example (first level from root of container). Here I also used 1.0.0 connector.
Here is the command:

```
pyspark --master yarn --jars wasb:///example/azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.2.0_2.11-1.0.0-uber.jar
```

When spark is ready, you can paste and run your commands and everything should work properly.

If you have any questions or anything is not clear, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Since I can not find the proper answer solution for the issue I would like to share my working configuration. My configuration is working for HDI 3.6 with Spark 2.1. PySpark script using Jupyther Notebook successfully reads and writes the data from Cosmos Document DB.

```
%%configure
{
 "name":"Spark-to-Cosmos_DB_Connector", 
 "jars": ["wasb:///cosmos-libs/azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.1.0_2.11-1.0.0-uber.jar"],
 "conf": {"spark.jars.excludes": "org.scala-lang:scala-reflect,org.apache.spark:spark-tags_2.11"}
}
```

Read and write configrations, read and save commands exactly the same like it is described in the question. Write config has additional parameter `WritingBatchSize` described [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark/tree/master/releases/azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.1.0_2.11-1.0.0). Uber jar I downloaded from this [location](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark/tree/master/releases/azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.1.0_2.11-1.0.0).

Comment: Exactly, HDI 3.6 and Spark 2.1 work well with Jupyter and 1.0.0 connector (important). Unfortunately - your approach wouldn't work in Spark 2.2 :( (for now, I hope they will fix it). You can also check my answer if you need Spark 2.2.